# Powershell in C# - Accessing Exchange

Tags: c#, powershell, syntax

I'm using the Powershell classes in the .NET System.Management.Automation* namespaces.  I need to translate this cmdlet call that sets a variable into C# syntax:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

Here is how I've been building Commands:

```
 List<Command> cList = new List<Command>();
 Command cEx = new Command("Set-ExecutionPolicy");
        cEx.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Scope", "CurrentUser"));
        cEx.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted"));
        cList.Add(cEx);
```

Later, I loop through the cList of commands and execute each as follows:

```
Pipeline pipeline;
        Collection<PSObject> exResults = null;
        foreach (Command cmd in cList)
        {
            pipeline = ps.Runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
            exResults = pipeline.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject p in exResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            }
        }
```

I need help getting the the syntax right for that 1st command that sets the $Session variable.  This is what I've tried but I don't think is correct:

```
 Command c10 = new Command("Set-Variable");
        c10.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Name", "Session"));
        c10.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Value", "New-PSSession"));
        c10.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange"));
        c10.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ConnectionUri", "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid"));
        c10.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Credential", pCredUser));
        c10.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Authentication", "Basic"));
        c10.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("AllowRedirection"));
        cList.Add(c10);
```

When the c10 command gets invoked, I get the Exception:"A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConfigurationName'"

Comment: *...but I don't think is correct.* Why? It looks like valid code to me. Does it work?

Comment: I get an Excption when Invoking the command - "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConfigurationName'",

Comment: So your error is caused by this line: `c10.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange"));`. You should edit your question to point that out.

Comment: @chade. THanks. I did. I'm just realizing the Exception may be that I don't have an Exchange SDK (or similar) on my dev machine as I'm not running this on an Exchange server.

Comment: So if that solves your problem, you should post an answer explaining how you did it. And yes, it is allowed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was trying to connect to Exchange 2010.

This post (and the articles linked therein) were helpful-
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/akashb/2010/03/25/how-to-migrating-exchange-2007-powershell-managed-code-to-work-with-exchange-2010/